# Symfony 2.6 with MSSQL Doctrine failed to update Database

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine, sqlsrv

**Hey Community,**

i have a Problem with Symfony 2 and Doctrine with a MSSQL-Database. On "php app/console doctrine:database:create" and "php app/console doctrine:schema:create" all fine. But on "php app/console doctrine:schema:update" without any changes in ORM-Mapper or Entity display following Error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE product DROP CONSTRAINT DF_D34A04AD_A5D6E63E':
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]DF_D34A04AD_A5D6E63E is not a restriction.
```

*PLEASE HELP*

When i delete the restriction manually from the table named "DF__product__timesta__38996AB5", its a new Error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE product ALTER COLUMN timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP':
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the DEFAULT keyword.
```

*PLEASE HELP*

**Database**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016
```

**Packages for PHP:**

```
php70.x86_64                        1.0-5.el7
php70-php.x86_64                    7.0.26-1.el7
php70-php-cli.x86_64                7.0.26-1.el7
php70-php-common.x86_64             7.0.26-1.el7
php70-php-json.x86_64               7.0.26-1.el7
php70-php-pdo.x86_64                7.0.26-1.el7
php70-php-sqlsrv.x86_64             4.3.0-1.el7
php70-php-xml.x86_64                7.0.26-1.el7
php70-runtime.x86_64                1.0-5.el7
```

**parameters.yml**

```
database_driver: sqlsrv
```

**src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php**
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

```
class Product
{
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $description;
    private $timestamp;
}
```

**src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Product.orm.yml**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    table: product
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 100
        price:
            type: decimal
            scale: 2
        description:
            type: test
        timestamp:
            type: datetime
            columnDefinition: DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            nullable: false
```

**Export structure of table panel.product**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "product" (
"id" INT(10,0) NOT NULL,
"name" NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
"price" NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
"description" VARCHAR(max) NOT NULL,
"timestamp" DATETIME(3) NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

**composer show -i**

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.6  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.4.1  Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                 v1.3.0  Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.5.0  Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                        v2.4.4  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             v1.5.0  Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       v1.0.1  Symfony2 Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/inflector                   v1.0.1  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/orm                         v2.4.7  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler v2.1.1  Composer script handling your ignored parameter file
jdorn/sql-formatter                  v1.2.17 a PHP SQL highlighting library
kriswallsmith/assetic                v1.2.1  Asset Management for PHP
monolog/monolog                      1.15.0  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
psr/log                              1.0.0   Common interface for logging libraries
sensio/distribution-bundle           v4.0.0  Base bundle for Symfony Distributions
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v3.0.9  This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sensio/generator-bundle              v2.5.3  This bundle generates code for you
sensiolabs/security-checker          v2.0.5  A security checker for your composer.lock
swiftmailer/swiftmailer              v5.4.1  Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/assetic-bundle               v2.6.1  Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
symfony/monolog-bundle               v2.7.1  Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v2.3.8  Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                      v2.6.11 The Symfony PHP framework
twig/extensions                      v1.2.0  Common additional features for Twig that do not directly belong in core
twig/twig                            v1.18.2 Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid syntax for adding default to a column:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE product ALTER COLUMN timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> ```

You should use

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 FOR [timestamp]
```

Or you can use a name for your constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 FOR [timestamp]
```

The first error that you receive is strange because when you try to drop non-existing constraint you should get

> 'DF_D34A04AD_A5D6E63E' is not a constraint.

The cause is you use wrong constraint name. It does not seem automatically generated default constraint name as when it's generated table name + field name are used. So check the constraint name once again.

Comment: ALTER TABLE product ALTER COLUMN timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Cannot change this code comes from doctrine.

    'DF_D34A04AD_A5D6E63E' is not a constraint.

This comes from doctrine to. Iam not sure where get doctrine this name.

Comment: >>>ALTER TABLE product ALTER COLUMN timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Cannot change<<< SQL Server parser will not accept non supported syntax only because it cannot be changed

Comment: >>>Iam not sure where get doctrine this name.<<< You can use SQL Server Profiler to catch all the queries sent to your server. So you can find if it goes to wrong table, maybe it does not use schema, etc